# Wicket FileUpload.getInputStream throwing nullPointerExceopti

Tags: file-upload, wicket

I have a method that reads in a file using the Wicket FileUpload class..

```
public int lineCountOfFile() throws IOException
{
    int count = 0;
    BufferedReader buffReader =
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(upload.getInputStream()));

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(buffReader, ',');

    while(reader.readNext() != null )
    {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

when the file is smaller maybe less than 50 lines.. I have no issues.. but I was testing reading in a large file so I copied and pasted a bunch of lines  maybe somewhere over 100 lines or so..

When I try to read in the file that has a lot more lines, I get these errors:

Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.upload.FileUpload.getInputStream(FileUpload.java:212)
    at com.wicket.BulkLoadPage.lineCountOfFile(BulkLoadPage.java:557)
    at com.wicket.BulkLoadPage.processLine(BulkLoadPage.java:428)
    at com.wicket.BulkLoadPage.access$0(BulkLoadPage.java:420)
    at com.wicket.BulkLoadPage$BatchLoaderProcessingThread.run(BulkLoadPage.java:1131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

looks like it is in the line:
                        BufferedReader buffReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(upload.getInputStream()));

What can be the issue?  Any idea for a work around? Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide the code snippet where you define variable 'upload'. The exception is probably belong that.

Comment: Hi Martin, I finally had a chance to look it over again and it looks like it was an issue with data interleave.. I ended up using synchronized and that solved it.

Comment: OK, that's fine you've solved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was data interleave. I solved this by synchronizing the methods.